# Android Mediaplayer, datasource api, Samsung s8+

Tags: android

I am playing MP3 file from url using Android MediaPlayer datasource API. On all the devices mp3 file is getting played in 2-3 seconds. But particularly on Samsung s8+ device it is taking around 60-70 seconds to start the preview. I have verified the server logs also it is returning the response for mp3 file immediately.

Datasource method:
`mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(musicUrl));`

Target SDK: `23`

MP3 file size is approx. 700 KB with 25-30 seconds duration.

update:
I am getting the following exception immediately after calling 'prepareAsync()'function but it plays after 60-70 seconds.
'setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider'

Comment: Please check how much time the "MediaPlayer.prepare()" method takes by placing a Log() call before and after it. It could be useful to help us. However did you tried to play a different MP3 file on that S8+?

Comment: I am calling player.prepareAsync(); method, callback method onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) is getting called after 60 seconds only. It works fine for MP3 file with size of 250-300 KB but files with 700KBs+ it is taking time.

Comment: But it's not normal. Maybe you have to look the Profiler and watch if the CPU is heavily used.

Comment: I have checked server logs, On server it is sending 15-20 requests for the preview url and finally it is playing after 50-60 seconds.

Comment: You have to run your App using the Android Studio's integrated Profiler and see how the CPU and Network are used. All other tests are useless. I think the solution is to create your own buffering, save it to a temp file and feed that to MediaPlayer.

This tutorial and source code explain exactly how. http://androidstreamingtut.blogspot.nl/2012/08/custom-progressive-audio-streaming-with.html
By adapting this code, it is easy to create a much better streaming player.